# What causes character counts from cin inaccurate and really large?

Tags: c++

I'm doing a character count via `char c = cin.get()`. Example of my output would be:
a: 53
b: 32
c: 29 *etc..*

For one of the alphabets, I'm getting an insanely large 9-digit number. And then when I use another input file that has more characters, the numbers are 6-digits and too large to be accurate. Any thoughts of this phenotype?

Again, sorry it's crunch time with the end of the semester. I appreciate any help out there.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

int count [26] = { };   
char alpha [26] = { };

char c;

c = cin.get();     
while(!cin.eof())
{
  if (isalpha(c))
  {
  c = tolower(c);      
  }    

  count [ c - 'a']++;
  alpha [ c - 'a'] = c;

  c = cin.get();
  }     

  for ( int i = 0; i<26; i++ )
     {
     cout << alpha[i] << ":" << count[i] << endl;
     } 

  } //end main
```

Here's the output:  (edited)

```
a:224
b:50
c:70
d:20
e:167772180
f:10
g:40
h:66
i:28
```

Here's the input:  (edited)

> aaaaaaaaAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBB

Made these changes, but it's still "hanging":

```
c = cin.get();     
while(c=cin.get())
{
  c = tolower(c);
  if (isalpha(c))
      continue;      


  count [ c - 'a']++;
  alpha [ c - 'a'] = c;

  }     

  for ( int i = 0; i<26; i++ )
     {
     cout << alpha[i] << ":" << count[i] << endl;
     } 

  } //end main
```

Comment: You shouldn't assume ASCII is in use, or use `while (!eof())`. Use `while (cin.get(c))` instead.

Comment: and obvious question, you enter all 26 pairs yes?

Comment: @KarthikT All 26 alphabets, some capitalized. But, each alphabet either consistently capitalized or in lower case.

Comment: I would suggest `int count [26] = {0};` and initialize your alphabet array somewhr else.

Comment: indeed while we are going into suggestions.. `std::map<char,int> charCounts;`

Comment: if that  is the case can you give some sample input/output?

Comment: @chris Could you explain why while(!eof()) shouldn't be used? I see it being used in class... (sometimes)

Comment: @chris Changing to while(cin.get()) makes my compiled code "hang"...

Comment: @harman2012, Work your loop around it. As for why the other is wrong, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: @KarthikT Okay I just added the input/output text. Sorry it takes up so much space! And I just realized that not all letters are consistently lower or upper case.

Comment: you can first try @Henrik's answer and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the input file contains anyting else than letters, anything can happen because you are accessing the array wtih out of bounds indices. Maybe you meant:

```
while(!cin.eof())
{
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        c = tolower(c);      

        count [ c - 'a']++;
        alpha [ c - 'a'] = c;
     }

    c = cin.get();
}
```

E.g. when your data contains a line feed character (10) you are accessing `alpha` with index 10 - 97 = -87. And this probably writes 10 into the most significant byte of `count[4]`.

Comment: Did you mean `(isalpha(c))`?

Comment: @harman2012 - just realized that `continue` would also skip the `cin.get()` at the end of the loop. Edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, the new line makes sense! Although looking at the file, a new line is returned at "s". I will scrutinize this new discovery. So the smaller file works and that makes sense to put the counts under isalpha(). Thanks so much!